# angularjs $resource update using PUT fails when parameter name changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm missing something in my understanding or code here...

I've got a very basic CRUD app to list/add/edit/delete categories, and it works fine when I define the primary key on the table as "id", but when I rename the database column to "categoryId", the PUT url does not include the key value, and I end up for a 404 error for an unhandled path...

stack:

IIS 7.5 w/ Slim PHP for RESTful services

```
// Route excerpt
...
          when('/categories',       {templateUrl: 'partials/categoryList.html',   controller: CategoryListCtrl}).
          when('/categories/new',   {templateUrl: 'partials/categoryDetail.html', controller: CategoryNewCtrl}).
          when('/categories/:id',   {templateUrl: 'partials/categoryDetail.html', controller: CategoryEditCtrl}).
...

angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']) 
.factory('Category', function($resource){ 
    return $resource('../api/index.php/categories/:id', {id:'@categoryId'}, 
        { update: {method:'PUT' } } 
     ); 
})




// WORKS when attribute is 'id'
.factory('Category', function($resource){
        return $resource('../api/index.php/categories/:id', {id:'@id'}, 
            { update: {method:'PUT' } }
        );
    })


// FAILS with 404 when attribute is 'categoryId'
.factory('Category', function($resource){
        return $resource('../api/index.php/categories/:id', {id:'@categoryId'}, 
            { update: {method:'PUT' } }
        );
    })
```

Of course there are a number of other places in the code where the name is changed, but the effect I'm seeing seems to be related to the ngResource.

The first method produces an URL that works...

```
 categories/1?description=null&name=Observation&report=null
/api/index.php
```

The second produces this...

```
 categories?categoryId=1&description=null&name=Observation&report=null
/api/index.php
```

with the 404 error due to the malformed path.

Is there another parameter (or directive or something) required to get the renamed attribute to be used in the URL?

Comment: Have you confirmed via something like advanced rest or fiddler that you can actually send a put to that url?

Comment: Using advance rest, I can confirm that the service works fine. Something is rewriting the path from **../categories/1** to **../categories/categoryId=1**. Or it is seeing the field categoryId as a new attribute and looking for **id** to plug in as part of the URL path.

Comment: I just tested this and it works fine.  You must have something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the put with the second resource and it works as expected.  The only way I could reproduce that was if I was issuing a GET instead of a PUT.  If you open this demo and view the network tab (chrome/etc) you can see what the put and what the get produce.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tI9KpqDp49pXuJJVjivm?p=preview

The GET produces the querystring parameterized data:

GET produces:

```
Request URL:http://run.plnkr.co/api/index.php/categories?categoryId=123
Request Method:GET
```

PUT produces:

```
Request URL:http://run.plnkr.co/api/index.php/categories/123
Request Method:PUT
```

Code:

```
   var test= $resource('../api/index.php/categories/:id', {id:'@categoryId'}, 
        { update: {method:'PUT' } }
    );

     var test2= $resource('../api/index.php/categories/:id', {id:'@categoryId'}, 
        { get: {method:'GET' } }
    );

    test.update({categoryId:123});
    test2.get({categoryId:123});
```

Comment: My example might be a little too short.. the problem is not with the URL, it appears to be related to how a "PUT" request is generated using a factory and $resource as in   
`angular.module('runningrightServices', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Category', function($resource){
  return $resource('../api/index.php/categories/:id', {id:'@categoryId'}, 
   { update: {method:'PUT' } }
  );
 })
`  

I updated the example above too.

Comment: Can you please add to your question the controller code that calls the service that fails.